# Why is Generics.Collections.TObjectList.List unsafe?

Tags: delphi, generics

`TList` and `TOjectList` in `Generics.Collections` have a `.List` property, which is an enumerator.

For instance:

```
oList := TObjectList<TItem>.Create;
// Add items to oList
for Item in oList.List do begin
  // Do something with Item
end;
```

This is neat, but has a drastic consequence.  `.List` just reads `FList` (a private declaration on `TList` and `TObjectList`), which is merely an `arrayofT`.

Since a dynamic array is doubled in size whenever an item is added beyond its size, it means it has space for non-used items.

In case you have added 3 `TItem`s, the actual `FList` is 4 items long, with the fourth (and last) item being `nil`.

Thus using `TObjectList`'s `.List` is unsafe, because it will likely throw an access violation, if your `TObjectList` doesn't have a `.Count` value with a power of 2 (e.g. 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, etc.).

The following code could likely throw an access violation:

```
for Item in oList.List do begin
  Writeln(Item.ClassName);
end;
```

Of course, the safe solution is a simple iteration using `.Count`:

```
for I := 0 to oList.Count - 1 do begin
  Item := oList.Items[I];
  Writeln(Item.ClassName);
end;
```

This is just not *as pretty* as the enumerator.  (You can also check if `Item` is `nil`, of course.)

My questions are thus:

- Why `.List` isn't an actual enumerator?
- And does `TList`/`TObjectList` *have* an actual enumerator?

Here is an example from a `TForm` (where `btn1` simply adds a line and `mmo1` is a `TMemo`).

```
procedure TForm2.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Line: string;
begin
  Line := 'Line';
  mmo1.Lines.Add(Line);
  fList.Add(Line);
  mmo1.Lines.Add(Format('Count: %d; Actual length: %d', [fList.Count, Length(fList.List)]));
  for Line in fList.List do begin
    mmo1.Lines.Add(Format('Found: "%s"', [Line]));
  end;
end;
```

Now, using `string` does not throw an access violation.  But when I have clicked 3 times, I get the following:

```
Count: 3; Actual length: 4
Found: "Line"
Found: "Line"
Found: "Line"
Found: ""
```

Comment: Do you have by accident a piece of code to prove your theory? I mean, not something that is "likely", but actualls *does* fail.

Comment: I have added an example.

Comment: I see. I just overlooked the `.List` part, because it is too far out for me to use a list this way. But you are right.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> `TList<T>` and `TOjectList<T>` in `Generics.Collections` have a `List` property, which is an enumerator.

No that is not so. The `List` property is a dynamic array. And dynamic arrays have built in support for enumeration.

> Since a dynamic array is doubled in size whenever an item is added beyond its size, it means it has space for non-used items.

That is also not true. Dynamic arrays are not automatically resized. They have to be explicitly resized with a call to `SetLength`. The `TList<T>` class manages capacity of the underlying dynamic array that stores the list content using calls to `SetLength`.

> Why is `List` not an actual enumerator?

The [`List`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Generics.Collections.TList.List) property was added recently, in XE3 if I recall. Its purpose is to allow direct access to the underlying list which is possible no other way.

Sometimes for the sake of efficiency you might prefer to avoid taking copies if you want to modify the content of the list. For instance suppose your list contains records that are 1KB in size. If you want to modify a single boolean within each record, without using the `List` property, you end up copying the entire 1KB record twice. Just to modify one boolean.

Of course the cost for gaining access to the underlying storage is that you are exposed to the internal implementation details. Embarcadero could have implemented functionality that would give you this access in a safer way but for whatever reason they chose this route. I think I might have made an indexed property that returns a pointer to an item.

So, that is really the only use case for the `List` property. Unless you really need direct access to the underlying storage, do not use `List`. Of course, it would have been nice had the documentation bothered to explain any of this, but there it is.

> Does `TList<T>` have an actual enumerator?

Yes it does.

```
var
  Item: SomeType;
  MyList: TList<SomeType>;
....
for Item in MyList do
  Item.Foo();
```

Comment: Thank you.  I had mistaken its usage, apparently.

Comment: Ultimately, `TObjectList<T>.List` is analogous to `TList.List`, which likewise provides direct access to the list's internal storage. In both cases, the size of the internal storage is given by the `Capacity` property, whereas the external size of the list is given by the `Count` property.

Comment: @Rob Well `TObjectList<T>` is derived from `TList<T>` and so the `List` property is defined in `TList<T>` and inherited.

Comment: I hadn't noticed that, David, but the gist of my comment still stands: Generic `TList<T>.List` is analogous to non-generic `TList.List`.

Comment: @Rob Yes. I'm quite sensitive to the contrast between `TList` and `TObjectList` in generic and non-generic forms. In non-generic forms, `TObjectList` would frequently be used with `OwnsObjects` set `False` because it's accessor property was typed `TObject` and thus more convenient than `TList`. For the generic versions, they are type safe and that consideration is removed. The only reason to use `TObjectList<T>` is that you set `OwnsObjects` to `True`.

Comment: They realized they needed that when using these lists in their own code. Sad enough that is a pretty big code smell given TEnumerable<T> already has something called ToArray (which would have needed to be rewritten to do the same as the List property does). Too bad class helpers for generic types are not possible

Answer (score -1):

Try changing it to

```
for Item in oList do begin
  Writeln(Item.ClassName);
end;
```

Not sure why the List is available, but dont use it. It is just an array, where some of the items can be nil.

Edit:

Example of how the use of .List can fail:

```
type
  TItem = class
    text : string;
  constructor Create(AText : string);
  end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  oList: TObjectList<TItem>;
  Item: TItem;
begin
  oList := TObjectList<TItem>.Create;
  oList.Add(TItem.Create('a'));
  oList.Add(TItem.Create('b'));
  oList.Add(TItem.Create('c'));
  // Add items to oList
  for Item in oList.List do begin
    memo1.lines.add(item.text);
  end;
end;

constructor TItem.Create(AText: string);
begin
  self.text := AText;
end;
```

Comment: I think this misses the point. Yes, by and large, don't use the `List` property. But there are indeed uses for `List`. Remember that not every `TList<T>` has `T` as a class. When `T` is a large value type then `List` becomes useful in some scenarios. That's why it was added.

Comment: -1. All you have to say about the `List` property is to not use it, and you don't really even say why. All your answer does is demonstrate the very same problem the question already described. Although you have made true statements, you have not answered the question that was asked.